# Trying to send dynamically generated (JSTL) HTML attribute value with AJAX to Spring controller, but the value is always the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jstl

I am iterating list of Java objects with JSTL in JSP-pages like this:

```
<ul>
  <c:forEach items="${listOfObjects}" var="o">
      <li id="ObjectID" value="${o.id}" onclick="JSCall()"><a class="style">${o.id}</a></li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This will print to me:
1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. to the end of the list. But when I am trying to pass ObjectID's value back to controller it will only print number 1 on each clicked link. ObjectID's value should be the same which is printed.

I use jQuery's AJAX implementation for passing ObjectID to my Spring controller.

```
function JSCall(){

  var variable = $('#ObjectID').val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajaxController.html",
        data: "variable=" + variable
   });
}
```

And then I have controller which listens to that GET.

```
@RequestMapping("ajaxController")
public @ResponseBody
String JSCall(@RequestParam(value="variable") Integer variable){

    System.out.println(variable); //prints only "1" on each link
    return variable;
}
```

I don't get this at all, because I think it should work like planned. Maybe someone will notice something?

Comment: Well, since `<li>` is not `<input>`, `<textarea>`, or `<select>`, I don't know what `.val()` will return for `<li>`. Try tro use `var variable = $('#ObjectID').attr('value');` And make sure that value is set in HTML. Moreover, it looks like you have multiple elements with same ID, haven't you? And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msh6622f/) for this.

Comment: "attr('value')" didn't change the result. If I change my value to static value like "value="100"" it will print 100 in my console so it is taking the value from there. And that's true that I have multiple li elements with the same ID when list is iterated, but I don't know what to do for that.

Comment: you can't duplicate ID's, pass element as argument to `JSCall` so you can isolate instance

Comment: @TomJoad how do you change value of `<li>`? Do you understand that `value` attribute is not standard for `<li>`? Did you check what `value`s `<li>`s have in rendered HTML? For multpile `<li>` you can use, for example, class instead of ID for selection: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msh6622f/1/) - note that I replaced this outdated inline JS `onclick=""`  with jQuery's click event handler. And [one more fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msh6622f/2/) with using `data-value` instead of `value` - it sounds much more correct for me.